# Ajax call undefined index

Tags: ajax, advanced-custom-fields, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get the content of an ACF field through an Ajax call. This is my callback function:

```
function my_ajax_request() {

      $id = $_POST['id'];

      if( have_rows('carousel_slide') ):

    // Loop through rows
    while( have_rows('carousel_slide') ) : the_row();

     // Load sub Fields
     $cta_text = get_sub_field('cta_text');

     // Allowed html
     $allowed_html = array(
       'strong' => array()
     );
    ?>

    <div class="cta-popup">
      <!-- Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="cta-modal-1<?php echo $id; ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <p><?php echo wp_kses( $cta_text, $allowed_html );?></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
<?php
   // End loop
   endwhile;
   // End if
 endif; ?>

</div><!-- end carousel-inner -->

<?php
die();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_ajax_request', 'my_ajax_request' );
```

And this is my Ajax call:

```
  jQuery('.btn').click(function () {
    var id = jQuery(this).attr('data-target').replace('#', '');
    console.log(id);
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: ajaxurl.url,
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            action: 'my_ajax_request',
            id : id
        },
        success: function (result) {
           jQuery('.modal').attr('id',id);
           jQuery(id).modal('show');
           alert(id);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("error");
        }
    });

});
});
```

The id comes from a button that when clicked should open a bootstrap modal. However, I keep getting the following notice:

**Notice: Undefined index: my_id in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/themes/my-teme/functions.php on line 61**

The idea is to use the id from the Ajax call on my_ajax_request(). What am I missing?

Comment: Note that `jQuery(id).modal('show');` won't work as you stripped the `#` out earlier. Your AJAX also directly inserts `id` into the HTML with no escaping, so if I make a request with the ID `"><h1>Hello world</h1></body></html>` the page will be trashed, or I could use it to insert script tags and launch attacks

Comment: Also have you considered using the newer REST API for your AJAX instead? Admin AJAX is an old and difficult API to use with many pitfalls and easy mistakes

Comment: Thanks. Will take a look into the REST API option.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 problems:

### Problem 1

Your AJAX endpoint looks  for `my_id`:

```php
      $id = $_POST['my_id'];
```

But your javascript sends `id`:

```js
            id : my_id
```

Importantly:

`id` != `my_id`

They do not match. There is no `$_POST['my_id']`, that's  why you get a PHP notice

### Problem 2

You're using `$_POST` but the code does not make a POST request:

```js
type: 'POST',
```

There is no `type` parameter, the jQuery docs say to use `method: 'POST'`

---

As a side note, a REST API endpoint would have complained that the required `my_id` parameter was missing, and it would have complained that no `GET` endpoint existed, making both problems super clear in human readable text.

Even if the AJAX endpoint starts working, consider migrating to a REST API endpoint, it will give you:

- human readable error messages
- dedicated fields for listing your parameters, who can access it, all implemented by WP Core so you know you didn't make a mistake or forget something
- a pretty permalink URL
- better authentication, and the option for remote API access with the use off additional plugins
- easier to debug code

Comment: Yes, didn't realise that. Thank you. But even fixing that typo the issue persists.

Comment: The  php notice? Or something else? When you say you  fixed the typo, how did you fix it? Please be more specific, and note that you asked why you get the PHP notice, not how to make your AJAX endpoint functional.

Comment: My bad. I apologise. I ensured the id on the Ajax matches the is on the callback but I still get the undefined index notice.

Comment: can I see how you did that?

Comment: I have update my code above to reflect the changes I have made. Still no luck though. I keep getting  Undefined notice: id

Comment: And you've manually confirmed that `id` does actually exist in both PHP and in JS? ( curious that you choose `id` rather than `my_id` ) Ignore any "it should be there" and examine it directly. E.g. does the jQuery attribute call actually work? If `$_POST` does not contain `id`, what does it contain? Is line 61 of `functions.php` actually your AJAX endpoint? Is caching turned off in your browser so you know it's using the  newer code not cached old code?

Comment: The js works fine part works fine. I'd like to pass this id to the callback function but that's where I get stuck. Keep getting the Undefined index id notice. I think I'll have to look into other options.

Comment: @Madeirense I found the problem, updating the answer

Comment: Thank you but it does not work. The problem is for some reason the id is not being passed to the callback so I get the Undefined index. I have done similar functionality before and never got this issue. Really annoying.

Comment: Because you are making a `GET` request then trying to use `$_POST`, it is your javascript at fault. As an aside, when you say it does not work, do you mean it still gives the PHP notice? I guarantee though, that `type: 'POST'` is incorrect

Comment: Also, have you inspected the contents of `$_GET` and `$_POST`? And confirmed that they contain what  you expect them to contain? Clearly a fundamental assumption is being made that is incorrect, we have already found 2 that turned out to be wrong. I strongly recommend simplifying this to just an AJAX endpoint that returns the ID, and a javascript snippet with a hardcoded `id` that can be pasted in the dev console for testing purposes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119005/discussion-between-madeirense-and-tom-j-nowell).